# ArcGIS character marker in geoserver

Tags: character, arcgis, geoserver

Does anyone have any experience using ESRI ArcGIS character marker symbols for point datasets in Geoserver for online map publishing. The character symbols I am interested in using is from the 'ESRI Enviro Hazard Sites' symbols for dolphin, manatee and whale.

Any advise would be much appreciated!

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to by using the < ExternalGraphic> tag in the SLD instead of a simple shape such as circle or square. Here is a sample from GeoServers [SLD Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/points.html#point-as-graphic) section point as graphic.

```
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
 <Rule>
   <PointSymbolizer>
     <Graphic>
       <ExternalGraphic>
         <OnlineResource
           xlink:type="simple"
           xlink:href="smileyface.png" />
         <Format>image/png</Format>
       </ExternalGraphic>
       <Size>32</Size>
     </Graphic>
   </PointSymbolizer>
 </Rule>
```